# How to uninstall Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Here Im getting a problem when Im uninstalling the Iphone sdk through terminal with the command as:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools mode=all;;
```

When I used this its displaying the command is not found.

Is there any other method to unistall Iphone sdk?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: Guys I need a propmt reply from u please can any one help me for his problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just be able to delete any *iPhone SDK* folders from the *Developer* folder.